# Display Django Model as a table

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 1.11 and I need some advice as to the best method to display a Model as a table in a template using Class Based Views. I'd like to be able to filter and sort the table as well. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried already ? Can you show us some of your code ?

Comment: So far I have taken a very basic approach and used a ListView. As i'm new to Django I'm just not sure if ListView is the best way to approach this or if there is a better method to display a Model as a table.

Comment: What you might want to look at is ModelForms. You can render such forms like `{{ form.as_table }}` Filtering/sorting can be supplied by JavaScript.

Comment: awesome! sytech. thanks for the feedback. i'll check that out now. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
[https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2](http://django-tables2)

It is having Pagination and column sorting features.

Comment: This suggestion was perfect and was exactly what I needed. Thank you TARUN and I recommend this solution to others in the same boat as me. For filtering I used django-filter.

Comment: Thank you. Please upvote my answer, if it is helpful to you.